# What are the differences between JDK dynamic proxy and CGLib in Spring and how do they impact memory usage?

Tags: java, spring

could someone help me to understand difference between JDK dynamic proxy and CGLib ?
and what is the default in spring ?

I know that JDK proxies support interface and CGLib supports subclasses . my goal is to understand memory usage of them

Comment: This answer explain how these two approach works . I want to know that why CGLib is more efficient than JDK dynamic proxy .